# Wrong URL for users - adds "undefined" to link

Tags: telescope

http://myapp.herokuapp.com/users/undefinedwilliamw

As you might have noticed, Telescope added "undefined" to the user URL. If you remove "undefined" it works fine.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more info to work on. Can you post some code, let us know where the issue might be.

Comment: Thank you. I did the one click deploy for heroku, does that help? I'm kinda new to all of this, so my apologies if i dont give you the correct information. To be honest, i have no idea where "undefined" is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually an Iron Router issue. If you come to the Slack chatroom I posted more info about this:

ok, it’s a temporary problem with Iron Router

sacha [2:43 PM]
you need to update it to 1.0.9

sacha [2:44 PM]
https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1359

sacha [2:58 PM] 
I updated the deployment page with instructions on how to update on Heroku

sacha [2:58 PM]
http://docs.telescopeapp.org/v0.20/docs/deploying (edited)

sacha [2:58 PM]
in this specific case, you want to upgrade the `iron:router` package to version `1.0.9`

sacha [2:58 PM]
you can make sure the update worked by checking your `.meteor/versions` file (edited)

sacha [2:59 PM]
for some reason it didn’t quite work the first time I ran `meteor update` for me, so you might have to delete the `versions` file and do it again